# update a page only when there are no mouse events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to update the page only when there are no mouse events,
Such as:

```
function TimedRefresh(t) {
    $('#colorbox').mousemove(event) {
        if (mousemove != 0) { //(mousemove == false)
            setTimeout("location.reload(false);", t);
        }
    }
}
```

It of course does not work. It's called by:

```
<body onload="JavaScript:TimedRefresh(5000);">
```

Comment: Reloading full page if no activity?! For me, it sounds like a XY problem...

Comment: various data coming from  DB but while I modify  a specific field the page must be fixed

Comment: It sounds like a job for ajax, no?!

Answer (score 1):

You'd do that like this

```
$('#colorbox').mousemove(function( event ) {

    clearTimeout( $(this).data('timer') );

    $(this).data('timer', setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.reload();
    }, 5000));
});
```

When the mouse moves within the `#colorbox` element, the timer is reset, and if no mouse movement is detected, it reloads the page in 5 seconds.

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/n7fkoad4/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to reverse the logic. Set the timer onload of the page and then clear/restart it when the mouse is moved. If the mouse is not moved for longer than 5 seconds, then the page will refresh:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var timer;
    resetTimer();

    $('#colorbox').mousemove(function() {
        resetTimer(timer);
    });

    function resetTimer() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            window.location.reload(false);
        }, 5000);
    }
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/r2pewyuv/)

Comment: as asked in: http: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35647754
but probably there was a misunderstanding, because I have not explained it properly.
how can I update only the id part (#colorbox) instead of the entire page?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do something likes this:

1. Create a hidden field with a default value (maybe 0).
2. When some MouseEvent is triggered then yo should change the value of the hidden field (maybe 1)
3. Then, for other side I think you could use a function like *setTimeout* for comparing and refresing your page. [Here you can read more about this function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)