# update a part of page only when there are no mouse events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

as my last question I received many Useful replies,

if I want update  instead a whole page only a portion of it  (id='#colorbox')

modifying the Rory McCrossan code  :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35579920/3387832

changing:

```
window.location.reload(false);
```

with:

```
$('#colorbox').load(window.location.href + ' #colorbox');
```

or

```
$('#colorbox').load('aa.html #colorbox').fadeIn();
```

or

```
 $('#colorbox').load('aa.html');
```

but none works fine

Comment: `if I want update instead a whole page only a portion of it (id='#colorbox')` AJAX..?

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax and bind the return data to a div with that color code

$('#divwiththatColor').html(result);

The return can be anything including a partial view

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, If I understand your problem correctly:

```
$.get(window.location.href, function(page) {
   $('#colorbox').replaceWith($(page).find('#colorbox'));
});
```